# Textures are not drawn separatley

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to draw different textures of balloons and I want them to appear in different times about half second between each one, and move in the world. first balloons are rendered but after about half second the other balloons are rendered next to the previous ones, not in the initial place:
this is code:

```
private Ballons ballons;
    private Ballons ballons2;
    private Ballons ballons3;
    private Ballons ballons4;

    private Texture background;
    public Celebration(Fruits game, float level)
    {
        this.game=game;
        this.level=level;
        gamecam=new OrthographicCamera();
        gameport=new StretchViewport(820/Fruits.PPM,580/Fruits.PPM,gamecam);
        stage=new Stage(gameport,((Fruits) game).batch);
        background=new Texture("Wining.jpg");
        gamecam.position.set(gameport.getWorldWidth()/2f,gameport.getWorldHeight()/2f,0);
        temp=0;
        counter=400;
        world=new World(new Vector2(0,0.5f),true);
        b2dr=new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        ballons=new Ballons(world,this,1,140);
        ballons4=new Ballons(world,this,2,290);
        ballons3=new Ballons(world,this,3,480);
        ballons2=new Ballons(world,this,4,650);


    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }
    public void handleinput(float dt)
    {
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
            game.setScreen(new GlobalWorld(game, 1));
    }
    public void update(float dt)
    {
        handleinput(dt);
        world.step(1 /60f, 6, 2);
        //player.update(dt);
        gamecam.update();
//        renderer.setView(gamecam);
        ballons.update(dt);
        ballons2.update(dt);
        ballons3.update(dt);
        ballons4.update(dt);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        float level;
        update(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        counter--;
        b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined);
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);

        game.batch.begin();

        game.batch.draw(background, 0, 0, gameport.getWorldWidth(), gameport.getWorldHeight());
        if (counter < 200) {
            ballons.draw(game.batch);
            ballons2.draw(game.batch);

        }
        if (counter < 100) {
            ballons3.draw(game.batch);
            ballons4.draw(game.batch);

        }
        game.batch.end();


    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gameport.update(width, height);


    }

}
```

Ballons class:

```
public class Ballons extends Sprite {
    public World world;
    public Body b2body;
    private TextureRegion collectorStand;
    public Ballons(World world,Celebration screen,float image, float x)
    {
       // super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("boy1"));
        this.world=world;
        defineCollector(x);
        if(image==1) {
            collectorStand = new TextureRegion(new Texture("Balloon1.png"));
            setBounds(0, 0, 200 / Fruits.PPM, 200 / Fruits.PPM);
        }
        else if(image==2) {
            collectorStand = new TextureRegion(new Texture("Balloon2.png"));
            setBounds(0, 0, 170 / Fruits.PPM, 185 / Fruits.PPM);
        }
        else if(image==3) {
            collectorStand = new TextureRegion(new Texture("Balloon3.png"));
            setBounds(0, 0, 150 / Fruits.PPM, 175 / Fruits.PPM);
        }
        else if(image==4) {
            collectorStand = new TextureRegion(new Texture("Balloon4.png"));
            setBounds(0, 0, 150 / Fruits.PPM, 175 / Fruits.PPM);
        }
        else if(image==5) {
            collectorStand = new TextureRegion(new Texture("Balloon5.png"));
            setBounds(0, 0, 150 / Fruits.PPM, 175 / Fruits.PPM);
        }
        setRegion(collectorStand);
    }
    public void update(float dt)
    {
        setPosition(b2body.getPosition().x-getWidth()/2,b2body.getPosition().y-getHeight()/2.8f);
    }
    public void defineCollector(float x)
    {
        BodyDef bdef=new BodyDef();
        bdef.position.set(x/Fruits.PPM,-20/Fruits.PPM);
        bdef.type=BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        b2body=world.createBody(bdef);
        FixtureDef fdef=new FixtureDef();
        CircleShape shape=new CircleShape();
        shape.setRadius(15/Fruits.PPM);
        fdef.shape=shape;
        b2body.createFixture(fdef);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter what actual `counter` value is you are calling `update(delta);` inside your `render` method. I see there

```
    ballons.update(dt);
    ballons2.update(dt);
    ballons3.update(dt);
    ballons4.update(dt);
```

Unfortunately you have not attached `Ballons` class implementation but I'm pretty sure that `update` method is modifying balloons'es positions.

You should call then ballon's `update` method inside your if-else statements rather not inside the `update` method. It could look like

```
    public void update(float dt)
    {
        handleinput(dt);
        world.step(1 /60f, 6, 2);
        //player.update(dt);
        gamecam.update();
        //renderer.setView(gamecam);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        ...

        if (counter < 200) {
            ballons.update(dt);
            ballons2.update(dt);

            ballons.draw(game.batch);
            ballons2.draw(game.batch);
        }
        if (counter < 100) {
            ballons3.update(dt);
            ballons4.update(dt);

            ballons3.draw(game.batch);
            ballons4.draw(game.batch);
        }
```

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it is the same, they still appearing at the middle of the screen with the previous ones

Comment: I added the balloons class to my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your update function is only fixing the position of the balloons to the Box2D body. Since the Box2D body is created and added to the world on creation, the body will still be moving even though it is not drawn.

You can disable the balloon's bodies until they are ready to be drawn, like so:

Balloons.java

```
public void defineCollector(float x) {
    BodyDef bdef=new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(x/Fruits.PPM,-20/Fruits.PPM);
    bdef.type=BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2body=world.createBody(bdef);
    FixtureDef fdef=new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape=new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(15/Fruits.PPM);
    fdef.shape=shape;
    b2body.createFixture(fdef);

    b2body.setActive(false);
}
```

Celebration.java

```
public Celebration(Fruits game, float level) {
    ...

    stage.addAction(
        Actions.sequence(
            Actions.delay(0.5f), 
            Actions.run(
                new Runnable() {
                    ballons.b2body.setActive(true);
                    ballons2.b2body.setActive(true);
                }
            ),
            Actions.delay(0.5f), 
            Actions.run(
                new Runnable() {
                    ballons3.b2body.setActive(true);
                    ballons4.b2body.setActive(true);
                }
            )
        )
    );
}

public void update(float dt) {
    stage.act(dt);

    ...
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    ...

    if (ballons.b2body.isActive()) {
        ballons.draw(game.batch);
    }
    if (ballons2.b2body.isActive()) {
        ballons2.draw(game.batch);
    }
    if (ballons3.b2body.isActive()) {
        ballons3.draw(game.batch);
    }
    if (ballons4.b2body.isActive()) {
        ballons4.draw(game.batch);
    }
}
```

I would recommend using Scene2D to handle your logic by changing your balloons to extend `Image` and adding your balloons to the stage like so: `stage.addActor(balloon)`. You can then handle your logic inside of the `act` method, and override `draw` to position the texture over the Box2D body.